# Percentage Text toward the inside the Graph Android Horizontal Progress Bar

Tags: java, android

Can you please help me.I am getting issue to the percentage is toward the top of the inside the graph.You can see in attached image.So i want the progress bar like this Image

I am using this code for Progress bar but not getting progress bar like bellow image

```
<LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:orientation="vertical"
                       android:paddingTop="@dimen/five"
                       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/five"
                       android:paddingRight="@dimen/five">

                       <TextView
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/five"
                           android:paddingTop="@dimen/five"
                           android:text="50"
                           android:textColor="@color/black"
                           android:textSize="@dimen/ten" />

                       <RelativeLayout
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="0dp"
                           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                           android:layout_weight="1">

                           <ProgressBar
                               style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                               android:id="@+id/progress_1"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                               android:max="100"
                               android:progress="30"
                               android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable1" />

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/progress_1_text"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:clickable="false"
                               android:gravity="top"
                               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten"
                               android:text="30%"/>

                       </RelativeLayout>

                   </LinearLayout>
```

[image]